# How do to implement type specified generic method?

Tags: c#, generics

I have class `MyClass<T> where T : IComparable` and I want to implement a method that will be called if `T` is `String`. How can I do that?

*Right now I have follow code:*

```
public void Method()
    {
        ... 

        Type typeParameterType = typeof(T);
        if (typeParameterType.Equals(typeof(String))) 
        {
            // here I can't do (String) anyTTypeValue
            // to call handleString(String) method
        }

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to do this. Would `T.ToString()` be useful?

Comment: Yes it's a solution too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
(string)(object) anyTypeValue;
```

By the way, you don't have to do all that -- you can just say:

```
if(anyTypeValue is string)
{
    string strValue = (string)(object)anyTypeValue;
    ...
}
```

Edit:

As @Ilya suggested, you can use `as` in case of reference types and `Nullable<T>` types. Since `string` is a reference type, you can do this:

```
var strValue = anyTypeValue as string;
if(strValue != null)
{
    ...
}
```

However, you could not do the same thing with an `int`:

```
var intValue = anyTypeValue as int; //compiler error
```

Also note that you cannot tell if `strValue != null` is false because `anyTypeValue` was `null` to begin with, or because `anyTypeValue` was *not a string*.

In some use cases, these are not an issue, so using `as` would be preferable.

Comment: won't that just throw 99% of the time?

Comment: No, because you check that it is a string before you call it.

Comment: It works. And it's a solution. But why I cannot jus `(String) anyTTypeValue`?

Comment: You can do that, but if the value isn't a string an exception will be thrown.

Comment: I ment that compliler dosn't let me do just `(String) temp.value` instead of `(String)(Object) temp.value`.

Comment: You have no constraint on type T to allow that cast. Even if you are doing that cast within a "safe" if statement the compiler doesn't know that.

Comment: +1, You've made good comments to my post. You definitely want to use `is` operator, when you want to handle `null` `string` or `struct` values.

Answer (score 3):

you can take take advantage of `as` operator and check if `valString` is not null. Then you will have access to `string` specific properties and methods. Next code snippet will show the main idea:

```
public void Method<T>(T val)
{
    string valString = val as string;
    if(valString != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine (valString.Length);
    }
}

Method("tyto"); //prints 4
Method(5); //prints nothing
```

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. Using `as` means you don't need to cast the object twice.

Comment: Thank you! It's a solution. But in my case I would prefer @Eren Ersonmez way because I have to cast it twice: `temp.value = (T)(Object) BalanceString((String)(Object) temp.value, balanseLength);`

Comment: You can also try cast `temp.value` to `string` using `as` operator

Comment: Yep. And I guess it works too! But if I forgot to cast it before it will throw no exception `temp.value = notString as String`, but that code will `temp.value = (String)(Object) notString`

Comment: Ok, good. I don't used to rely on cast exceptions and I would specifically handle when result is `null`, but anyway, I was happy to help.

Comment: Note that there are two issues to this method: 1) you cannot differentiate between _T not being a string_ vs. _T being a null string_. 2) you can not use this with value types (except Nullable<T>), so you cannot say `int i = val as int;`. If both of these are non-issues, then this would be preferable.